# How to prevent listView on escalating columns and bind it to ViewModel?

Tags: c#, wpf

I have C# WPF listview that generates columns base on date range..
how could i prevent escalating columns? how  cant i mange to do single instance on generating columns?
[image: ListView]

And how can i bind it on my view model?

Comment: I have edited your title. Please see, "[Should questions include “tags” in their titles?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/19190/)", where the consensus is "no, they should not".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Is the issue that each time you click the "Generate" button it appends columns? If this is the case then the only thing you should be adding is

```
private void CreateColumns()
{
    myView.Columns.Clear();
    //...
}
```

To the beginning of your CreateColumns method.

Comment: Have an ObservableCollection of dates in the viewmodel and an ICommand using a RelayCommand implementation for the button to trigger. The method in the viewmodel bound to the ICommand calculates and sets your ObservableCollection to the new set of date values and the UI binding should take care of the rest. (including formatting the dates *see StringFormat on Bindings.) You may need to raise a PropertyChanged event for the collection's property when setting the new list of dates.